# Textarea not sending on submit

Tags: php, forms, textarea, submit

Arg, this is so annoying!

I've got a form with a textarea. On submit I use a piece of php to send the data of the form to my email adress. The other data is sending fine (input) but it doesn't send the textarea along!

This is de PHP:

```
parse_str($_POST['stuff']);
mail("name@myemailadress.nl", "Website formulier", $name, $email, $comments);
```

This is the code:

```
<form class="form" id="form" action="" method="POST" >
    <p class="name">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="NAAM" >
    </p>
    <p class="email">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-MAILADRES" >
    </p>    
    <p class="text">
        <textarea name="comments" id="bericht" placeholder="BERICHT" ></textarea>
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" id="versturen_knop" class="submitBtn" value="VERSTUREN" >
    </p>
</form>
```

This is the code that changes the state of the submit button for 3 seconds (message send confirmation) and triggers the PHP

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(event){
        $('.submitBtn').attr('value','BERICHT VERSTUURD!');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.submitBtn').attr('value','VERSTUREN');
        }, 2000);
        var stuff = $('#form').serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mail.php', 
            data:{ 'stuff':stuff, }
        });
        //Prevents form submission
        return false;        
    });
});
```

I hope you can help!

Comment: So where do you receive your textarea contents? Show some code.

Comment: Are you expecting text area contents to be automatically available as $comments in PHP?

Comment: Where is the teaxtarea!

Comment: you need to assign textarea value to the $comments. $comments = $_POST['comments']

Comment: Are you sure the other fields are sending? parse_str is only supposed to work on things in the query string format...

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe, `serialize()` prepares a query string.

Comment: what is `parse_str($_POST['stuff']);` here?

Comment: Do you use a rich text editor with your textarea? If so, which one?

Comment: @SheikhHeera Ah, didn't see that, thanks.

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe, it happens, welcome :-)

Comment: I'm using textwrangler as text editor. I am not that good with coding these kind of things. The only thing I want is to send these data to my mail adress. If you know a better way of doing this, please share:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it works,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form class="form" id="form" action="" method="POST" >

            <p class="name">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="NAAM" >
            </p>

            <p class="email">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-MAILADRES" >
            </p>    

            <p class="text">
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="BERICHT" ></textarea>
            </p>

            <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" id="versturen_knop" class="submitBtn" value="VERSTUREN" >
            </p>
            </form>
        <script>    

            $(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').submit(function(event){
    $('.submitBtn').attr('value','BERICHT VERSTUURD!');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.submitBtn').attr('value','VERSTUREN');
    }, 2000);

    //var stuff = $('#form').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mail.php', 
        data : $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json"
    });

    //Prevents form submission
    return false;        
});
});

</script>



<?php
parse_str($_POST['stuff']);

mail("aa@ss.com", "Website formulier", "$name, $email, $comments");



?>
```

You need to add entire contents in double quotes. I have tested it, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
<?php
    mail("name@myemailadress.nl", "Website formulier", $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['comments']);
?>
```

Comment: This won't help. As you should have noticed, he is using the ridiculously named `parse_str()`, which dumps all array contents into local namespaced variables.

Comment: Correction, query string format contents, not array contents.

Comment: So, how should my php be to be able to send the 'comments' along with 'name' and 'email'?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the circumstances, I suspect you are using a rich text editor like CKEdit or TinyMCE on your textarea.

If such is the case, you should know that these editors do not directly influence the textarea's text, and you must call a special editor-specific method to update it's contents. This method is called automatically on form submit, but for serializing and submitting forms via ajax it is not as straightforward.

If this is the case, please let me know which editor you are using and I can tell you how to correctly prepare the textarea for serialization.

Comment: I'm using TextWrangler... Hope that helps!?

Comment: @user1737979 Not quite. TextWrangler is the program you edit your source code in, right? I was referring to any JS text plugins that you have attached to the textarea that make editing comments easier. Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

Change following line

```
data : { 'stuff':stuff, }
```

to

```
data : stuff
```

or you can use

```
data : $('#form').serialize();
```

or you may try

```
data : {
    'name' : $('#name').val(),
    'email' : $('#email').val(),
    'comments' : $('#bericht').val()
}
```

and retrieve using

```
$_POST['name']
$_POST['email']
$_POST['comments']
```

Comment: Quote: 'The other data is sending fine'.